# Bootstrap 4 Carousel transition unexpected behaviour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, transition, conflict

I'm developing a WordPress theme with Bootstrap 4 and I'm having a problem a carousel in the landing page.

The images are transitioning through a "white slide", either with the default slide transition (class="carousel slide) or with the fade transition (class="carousel slide carousel-fade").

I think I've read every thread on the internet regarding this issues but to no avail.

The website I'm working on is https://wws2018.it. I wanted to give you a jsfiddle but the one I made was working. I'm having a really hard time figuring out what my problem is.

Comment: well it seems to me that since the fiddle works that it points to something in your development environment.  I suggest you reduce the complexity of your environment. Temporarily comment out other non essential css and js, add-ins, etc. basically reduce it to a "bare bones" environment until it begins to work as expected and then begin adding things back one at a time to see what is stepping on the transition.  You may just need to re-order some items.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. That's exactly what I've been doing for hours but nothing seems to work...I guess I'll keep trying.